# Accessing gem class methods in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created my own gem 'mygem'. In the lib directory I have mygem.rb ruby file. This file has 3 methods defined.

Now I have created a rails app and I intend to use my gem in this app. In the controller ruby file I want to create a object and use the methods of my gem. But it is giving me error.

Here is the code of my controller ruby file:-

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  obj= Newgem.new()    

  def home
    @message1 = obj.head
    @message2 = obj.paraone
    @message3 = obj.paratwo
  end  
end
```

Comment: Could you show us your `Newgem` code?

Answer (score 0):

local variables (ones without an @ sign) will not carry through from the class scope to inside a method.  It's not clear to me what you are trying to do, but you could perhaps do it in a before_filter, like so:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :create_newgem

  def home
    @message1 = @obj.head
    @message2 = @obj.paraone
    @message3 = @obj.paratwo
  end  

protected
  def create_newgem
    @obj = Newgem.new()  
  end
end
```